# angular4 data table Error as ./node_modules/angular-4-data-table/src/index.ts

Tags: angular4-forms, angular-datatables

Im getting error as after i install datatabel   npm install angular-4-data-table --save

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-4-data-table/src/index.ts
Module build failed: Error: C:\SOFT\Angular\Angular\node_modules\angular-4-data-table\src\index.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
```

Answer (score 1):

You are certenly using a  higher version of angular which is not well organised with angular-data-table4 then upgrade for 5 version of the grid :

npm install angular5-data-table --save
and in App Module use:
import {DataTableModule} from 'angular5-data-table';
use in component
import { ... } from 'angular5-data-table';

it worked for me